# Record count varies from query

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am struggling to see why my record count is varying from my query statement. Now being a new user, it is something I have obviously not coded correctly, but cannot see it. If I run my query in access it returns the correct number of records, but in vb.Net, it returns a completely different figure.

For example, In my code

```
Sub filllistview()
    Try
        'creatconn()
        oledbCnn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.storageConnectionString
        oledbCnn.Open()
        'Dim oledbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select TOP 100 * from Postings WHERE Customer = '" & newvar & "' ORDER BY Date DESC", oledbCnn)
        'dr = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader()

        'drcount = Convert.ToInt32(dr("RowCount"))
        Dim oledbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select TOP 100 * from Postings " & _
                           "WHERE Customer = ? ORDER BY Date DESC", oledbCnn)
        oledbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", newvar)
        Using dr = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader()


            'clear items in the list before populating with new values
            ListView1.Items.Clear()

            While dr.Read()

                ListView1.Items.Add(CDate(dr(4)).ToShortDateString()).UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(1).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(11).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(7).ToString())
                With ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(CDbl(dr(5)).ToString("C"))
                    If CDbl(dr(5)) < 0 Then
                        .ForeColor = Color.Red
                        .BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
                        '.Font = New Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
                    Else
                        .ForeColor = tmpColor
                    End If
                End With
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(14).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString())
                count += 1

            End While
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show(CStr(ListView1.Items.Count - 1))
        MessageBox.Show(count.ToString)

        'If (count < 100) Then
        '    MessageBox.Show("less than 100")

        'Else
        '    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString)
        'End If

        'autosize each column in listview
        For Each col As ColumnHeader In ListView1.Columns
            col.Width = -2
        Next col

        'refresh the list with new data
        ListView1.Refresh()

        'Enable the posting previous button
        'btnNextPostings.Enabled = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        'dr.Close()
        oledbCnn.Close()
    End Try

    'btnNextPostings.Enabled = ListView1.Items.Count > 100

    gbxPostings.Text = "Client Postings for: " & "( " & newvar & " )" & " Total Records: " & count

    If (ListView1.Items.Count < 100) Then
        btnNextPostings.Enabled = False
        btnNextPostings.Text = "No data to show"
    Else
        btnNextPostings.Enabled = True
        btnNextPostings.Text = "Next " & CStr(ListView1.Items.Count - 1) & " Postings"
    End If

End Sub
```

Where have I gone wrong. Many thanks

Comment: ListView1 already have  some thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forget to call the ExecuteReader on the command, so, if the reader instance has already been initialized by a previous command you are looping on the content previously loaded.

```
Dim oledbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select TOP 100 * from Postings " & _
                               "WHERE Customer = ? ORDER BY [Date] DESC", oledbCnn)
oledbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", newvar)
Using OleDbDataReader dr = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader()
   While dr.Read()
      ....
   End While
End Using
```

I have also changed your command text from string concatenation to a parameterized query. It is important to use parameterized queries to avoid sql injections and parsing problems. Another change is to [Using Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440607/record-count-varies-from-query/20440705#20440705) around the disposable objects (the most important one is the connection but in your code is not clear how you initialize it). Finally the word DATE is a reserved keyword with Acces Jet Engine used by the OleDbProvider when you connect to Access db. You need to put square brackets around this word.

Of course, if you want an exact count of the items inside the ListView you should remove (clear) the previous content with a call to [ListView.Items.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before starting the reading loop and to be sure to have to `count` global variable correctly initialized to zero.

Comment: Thank you. However, it is giving me an error of: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' in my dr.Close() Finally
            dr.Close()
            oledbCnn.Close()

Comment: Well this part of your code is not shown above. The using statement closes the OleDbDataReader and dispose it, so there is no more need to call the close on it. But you should add this part of the code to your question (also the part where you initialize the connection)

Comment: steve, I have updated my code to reflect the changes based on your code suggestion. I am still getting varied results as per my original question. Thanks

Comment: Also the variable `count` is not declared and initialized anywhere in this code. Do you set it to zero before starting the loop?

Comment: Dim count As Integer = 0

Comment: Use the debugger to check the values. Put a breakpoint before entering the loop and check the count value then run till the end of the loop and check again that count variable

Comment: I shall try that. Another point is in my access query, I am asking it to fetch 100 records. Why is there more records being displayed in the listview.

Comment: I debugged as you suggested and the count for one client was 105. That client has a total of 774 records in the db.Another client showed 99 out of 1200 records. I don't understand why I cannot just pull 100 records and show in listview. Thanks

Comment: Cannot help more without the database. The code seems correct. If it is possible you could share the db and I gladly will take a look.

Comment: The thing is steve is that if I run in access 2010 it returns the correct record numbers and data. However, when I run in listview1, only the ref no field is showing data until the last record when the other fields are also displayed. I cannot share the db because of sensitive client data.

Comment: Well fine, but now I am curious. What was the problem?